# Cannot upload file with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Here' my code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("Page opened, ready to upload file.  Status is", status);
    var inputEl = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=file]")[0];
    console.log("Upload=" + JSON.stringify(inputEl)); // <---- NULL here
    page.upload(inputEl, 'C:/temp/1.JPG'); // <--- so this throws error
    page.evaluate(function () {
                var inputEl = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=file]")[0]; // <--- Not NULL here but...
                page.upload(inputEl, 'C:/temp/1.JPG'); // <--- cannot call page.upload from inside page.evaluate
    });
}, 5000);
```

As stated in the comment here, the problem is that I cannot make the program upload a file (image actually), what could be wrong in my code?

**UPDATE**

Here's another code I tried:

```
inputEl = page.evaluate(function(s) {
                  console.log("Selector=" + s);
                  var el = document.querySelectorAll(s)[0];
                  //console.log("(1)Upload=" + JSON.stringify(el));
                  return el;
              }, 'input[type=file]');
              console.log(inputEl.tagName); // output = INPUT
              console.log(inputEl.id); // output = id of element, OK
              page.uploadFile(inputEl.id, "C:\\temp\\1.JPG");
```

Comment: only in the `page.evaluate` callback you can access input elements, I think, this does mean that the callback runs in a [sandboxed mode](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) inside the loaded page (so you cannot access any variables that were seemingly in scope from your point of view). I guess you could try to set the elements and trigger an upload, I am a bit curious to the timeout need, aren't you using the [`page.open`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open.html) callback to wait till the page got loaded?

Comment: The setTimeout was added because prior to this a login was clicked

Comment: The updated code is correct, does it not work for you? How do you know?

Comment: The code works now, apparently, a phantom.exit is causing the upload to prematurely close.